# Заполнить массив элементами расположенных волной

Tags: c++, массивы

Подскажите, как заполнить массив псевдослучайными элементами(с 30, 50 и 100) расположенных волной? ( Меньший элемент, больше чем предыдущий, больше чем предыдущий, меньше чем предыдущий, меньше, меньше, больше предыдущего...)
[image: Пример]

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что значит волной, не совсем понятно

Comment: То есть, если нарисовать график и интерполировать по заданным точкам, то должна получится идеально-равномерная волна, как синусоида, допустим, или волны могут быть разной длины?

Comment: Волны могут быть разной длины

Comment: Еще уточнение, как плотно могут находится точки, и должно ли быть одинаковое количество точек на "каждой волне"? Может ли на первой волне быть 30 точек, а на второй 3-5?

Comment: Плотность точек на каждой волне одинаковая, желательно, от 3 до 5.

Comment: @Infaramal, если я Вас понял правильно, вот пример двух волн, значения которых от 0 до 100 и они состоят из 5 элементов каждая.
17 89 93 15 1 - первая волна 3 98 99 44 13 - вторая волна.
Если верно, могу подсказать как сделать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Допустим, у нас будет функция, `std::vector<int> GenerateAppropriateArray();`, которая будет возвращать массив (в данном случае, для удобства используется `std::vector<int>`) значений, которые будут случайным образом сгенерированы и образовывать "волну".

Предположим, изначально интервал, из которого выбираются числа не задан.
При вызове функции задаем интервальные значения `a` и `b`.

Далее, мы будем генерировать волну путем обрезания интервала, чтобы значения не были меньше или больше предыдущих.

Интервал мы будем обрезать слева, если мы не дошли до средины волны, и справа, если мы пересекли средину.

Допустим, у нас интервал от 1 до 100 и волна состоит из 5 элементов, то вот 5 шагов получения нужных чисел:

1) выбираем случайное число от 1 до 100, допустим 5 - наш первый элемент

2) выбираем от 5 до 100, получаем 85 - второй

3) выбираем от 85 до 100, получаем 95 - третий

4) сновы выбираем из начального интервала, то есть от 0 до 100, получаем 50 - четвертый

5) выбираем от 0 до 50, получаем 13

Конченая волна :

5, 85, 95, 50, 13

Возможно, в коде будет проще разобраться, написал на быструю руку, но как пример для вдохновления, надеюсь, Вам поможет:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int random(int from, int to)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<>urd(from, to);
    return urd(mt);
}

std::vector<int> GenerateAppropriateArray()
{
    constexpr int NumberOfElementsInEachWave = 5;
    std::vector<int> Result;
    int a;
    int b;
    int NumberOfWaves;

    std::cout << "enter left boundary of interval" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "enter right boundary of interval" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "enter number of waves in array" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> NumberOfWaves;



    for (auto i = 0; i < NumberOfWaves; i++)
    {   
        int RandomNumberFromInterval;
        int CurrentLeftBound = a;
        int CurrentRightBound = b;

        for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfElementsInEachWave; j++)
        {
            RandomNumberFromInterval = random(CurrentLeftBound, CurrentRightBound);
            Result.push_back(RandomNumberFromInterval);
            if ((NumberOfElementsInEachWave + 1) / (j + 1) > 2)
            {
                CurrentLeftBound = RandomNumberFromInterval;
                CurrentRightBound = b;
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentLeftBound = a;
                CurrentRightBound = RandomNumberFromInterval;
            }
        }
    }

    return Result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> Check = GenerateAppropriateArray();
    for (auto e : Check)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
}
```

Если будут вопросы, пишите в комментарий.

Вот пример моих волн: 

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]